# Arduino DUE and a ledmatrix with issues

Tags: arduino-due, spi

I am trying to code something for fun using an Arduino Due and a LED matrix. The led matrix has a [backpack controller](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/rgbmatrixbackpack_userguide.pdf). This device is using SPI. So I connect MOSI and SCLK to their respective pins and SS to pin 10 on the Due. So far so good.

The problem I have is that when i run my rudimentary code nothing happens.
this is the current code I am using. I thought this should be enough, but it clearly isn't.

```
#include <SPI.h>
void setup() {
  SPI.begin(10);
  SPI.transfer(10, 0x26, SPI_CONTINUE); //setup the matrix
  for (int i = 0; i<64; i++){
    SPI.transfer(10, 0x00, SPI_CONTINUE); //set all pixels to black...
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 Erase flash
 Write 10444 bytes to flash
 [                              ] 0% (0/41 pages)
 [=======                       ] 24% (10/41 pages)
 [==============                ] 48% (20/41 pages)
 [=====================         ] 73% (30/41 pages)
 [============================= ] 97% (40/41 pages)
 [==============================] 100% (41/41 pages)
 Verify 10444 bytes of flash
 [                              ] 0% (0/41 pages)
 [=======                       ] 24% (10/41 pages)
 [==============                ] 48% (20/41 pages)
 [=====================         ] 73% (30/41 pages)
 [============================= ] 97% (40/41 pages)
 [==============================] 100% (41/41 pages)
 Verify successful
 Set boot flash true
 CPU reset.
```

[image: Image of the ever unchanging LED-matrix]

So my question is: am I doing something wrong? what? 
Or is the Led matrix broken?

Hoping for good answers.
regs 
KB